# Get Comments For Dynamic Placement Creative Facebook Ads

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to pull comment data from ads with dynamic placement creative but I cannot get the correct post ID from the ad via the API.

I can do this for static ads by querying the Graph API for the 'effective_object_story_id' that is associated with the creative for my ad. I can then use the returned ID to get the comments from the post.

Whilst I do get an 'effective_object_story_id' for ads with dynamic creative, using this to get comments doesn't work. It gives me no comment data despite the fact I can clearly see that many comments have been made on the post. It also shows me "{{product.brand}}" when I look at the post object via the API suggesting that it isn't directing me to the post with comments but instead  some kind of shell object for the dynamic post.

Is it possible to get comments for ads with dynamic creative via the API? If so, how?

Comment: Same issue here. Can't fetch comments from dynamic ad creatives.

Comment: @RonakShah unfortunately not. If you find a solution, I'd love to know.

Comment: Did you find out how to retrieve the comments?

Comment: @LauraUzcategui sadly no. I would love to know if you or anyone else has figured it out.

Comment: I am also experiencing issues with this. I can extract comments for page posts but not ads. If you did find a solution, it would be great if you could share. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

it's because dynamic creative will automatically create multiple post_ids, so you need to manually find out all those posts, you can get those here:
`https://business.facebook.com/content_management/ADS_POSTS?context_id=${facebookPageId}&context_type=page`